# Linq query from datasource with where ... like '%%' or ... like '%%'

Tags: c#, database, linq, select, filter

I'm trying to select all the fields from a db that contains any of the string contained in a list (that could be populated from user).
Is very easy for me to do by pure SQL with a sentence like

```
WHERE myfield LIKE '%nam%' OR myfield LIKE '%cod%' OR myfield LIKE '%big%'
```

but I need to do it with C# and Linq. I searched several solutions, some that recommend me to use .Any or .Contains but I didn't get it how to apply to my case :-(

This is the most close result I can achieve:

```
var query = DataSource.Docs();

...

IList<string> nameFilter = new List<string>() {"nam", "cod", "big"};                    
query = query.Where(x => x.NomeFile.Contains(nameFilter.FirstOrDefault()));
```

anyway with this silly code I filter just the elements are containing the first element of my list (the FirstOrDefault let ignore all the others)

Can anybody help me to find the right way?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for:

```
query.Where(x => nameFilter.Any(s => x.NomeFile.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: I works like a charm! Thank you! I tried the combination of Any and Contains, but I was completely missing the order.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

`query = query.Where(x => nameFilter.Any(n => x.NomeFile.Contains(n)));`

or

`query = query.Where(x => nameFilter.Any(n => x.NomeFile.IndexOf(n) >= 0));`

Comment: this is literally no different at all than the other posted answer.

Comment: Thank you Michael!